# Android app crashes when no value is in edit text

Tags: android, crash, android-edittext, textwatcher

I am making a unit converter, but if I do not enter any value into edit text and press the calculate button the app crashes with error `Invalid float: ""`. Also, I want to forbid zeroes from being entered before numbers (eg. 0300). How do I accomplish this?

```
   //handle calculate
   calcButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.calcButton);

    calcButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.unit_spinner);
            String spinnerText = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            EditText unit_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.unit_edit);
            amount = Float.valueOf(unit_edit.getText().toString());

            if (unit_edit.getText().toString().equals(null)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert Value To Convert",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {

                switch (spinnerText) {
                    case "Kilograms":
                        kilograms = amount;
                        grams = amount * 1000;
                        ListView();
                        break;
                    case "Grams":
                        grams = amount;
                        kilograms = amount / 1000;
                        ListView();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Would be ideal if you can post the exception also..

Comment: Maybe you should use `unit_edit.getText() == null` than `unit_edit.getText().toString().equals(null)`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an `NumberFormatException` thrown since the `EditText` fields text is `""` and `""` is not a valid `float` value, the exception is thrown at the following line:

```
amount = Float.valueOf(unit_edit.getText().toString());
```

What you'll need to do is add some validation and checking before trying to get the `float` value of a `String`.

Check the methods documentation for more details http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You can't parse an empty value to float. You should first test if it's empty, and then do what you want, something like this:

```
String text = unit_edit.getText().toString();
if(!text.isEmpty()){ // Test if the text is empty
    if(text.matches("[0-9]+")){ // Test if it only contains numbers, using REGEX

        amount = Float.valueOf(text); // Only then parse to float.
        // Switch and rest of the stuff

    } else {            
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Use only numbers from 0 to 9.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The field is empty",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The comments explain what's going on. About the leading 0 in some numbers, using "valueOf" will remove it already, and `0300` will be parsed as `300`, so there's nothing to worry about.If you still want something related to it, let me know and i'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for your `EditText` to limit input to numbers only.

```
 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/unit_edit"
     android:inputType="number"
 />
```

You can also limit the digits, type of number such as decimal

```
 <EditText
   android:id="@+id/unit_edit"
   android:digits="0123456789."
   android:inputType="numberDecimal"
 />
```